# Understanding mathematically the promotion of field/observable to operator in QFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, field-theory

First, I know it "worked", in physics sense.

My question is what happened in the math sense.

1. When promoting something, such as a field, to an operator, am I essentially mapping the field to (infinitely dimension) operator that depends on spacetime? And the canonical commutator just somehow followed from this map (my guess is that the map somehow preserve the Poisson bracket and somehow map the bracket to commutator.. or maybe we can just get it somehow from operator's dependence on spacetime?)?
2. Alternatively, could it be that I am mapping the field to a more intricate mathematical object that encompasses canonical commutator (as well as other symmetry and their generator? as the operator version of the charge just somehow works quite well as a generator)?

Comment: I think you have it in reverse in (1.). As input we have two things, an equation of motion (the Klein-Gordon equation) and the commutation relations of $\phi$ and $\pi$ (or equivalently of $a$ and $a^\dagger$). Solutions to the equation of motion could be simple functions. But to satisfy the commutation relations, we **have to consider** operator-valued distributions as possible solutions. I think this is often called a "promotion" just because one first motivates what kind of solutions we have to consider and then only has to put hats on the operators. But you can just start with operators.

Comment: I guess it's not quite as well-defined a map. Rather, you have a (classical) theory, and then you (heuristically) construct a new ("quantised") theory which is in various ways modelled on the classical one, but for each degree of freedom (position/momnetum/field), you introduce an operator acting on some suitably-chosen space. Some properties of those operators are specified based on the classical theory, and some others you choose to make the quantised theory work mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

When you promote a field to an operator what you are doing is promoting a field, ie a tensor-valued function on spacetime, to an object called an operator-valued distribution over spacetime.
This is a map which maps distributions over spacetime to operators on a chosen Hilbert space. The Canonical Commutation Relations (CCRs) are embedded in the Hilbert space, so your quantum fields inherit them from the structure you put on the Hilbert space.

To construct a quantum theory from a classical one you do the followin:

- you choose your degrees of freedom
- you embed them into an Hilbert space
- you represent on the Hilbert space classical observables and fields over spacetime $\mathbb{M}^4$ as operator-valued distributions.

To be specific:

**(Classical field)**

$\phi: \mathbb{M}^4 \rightarrow V$
For V a chosen vector space, could be $\mathbb{R}$ or any tensor space really.

**(Quantum Field)**

$\hat{\phi}: \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{M}^4) \rightarrow \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$

For $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ the set of bounded operators on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{M}^4)$ the adeguate space of test functions on spacetime